# Caching doesn't work Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm following the 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4' book and I'm stuck at page 105 about the caching.
I have the following code in `index.html.erb`

```
<% if notice %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
      <div class="entry">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
        <div class="price_line">
            <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The first doubt is the following:
1) What does `cache ['store', Product.latest]` exactly do? It creates a cache, available from all StoreController actions, named "store" and associates the cache with the Product.latest: why should I do the last thing? Why do I need to associate my cache to a Product.latest?

Always at the same page the book says: "As far as verifying that this works, unfortunately there isn't much to see. If you go to that page, you should see nothing change, which in fact is the point! The best you can do is to make a change to the template anywhere inside the cache block without updating any product and verifying that you do not see that update because the cached version of the page has not been updated".

So I tried something like this:

```
<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
  "hello"
  ........
  ........
<% end %>
```

But I still get this update, the page shows me the "hello" string, why is it so? Shouldn't I see it?

P.S. Obviously I edited my `config/environments/development.rb` and restarted the server

Comment: Did you add more products in the meanwhile? That is, did `Product.latest` change?

Answer (score 0):

Start your application on production mode and you will see that caching works.
What did you edited in development.rb? Please compare it to production.rb and copy-paste all caching configuration properties.

Comment: Changing `config.cache_classes = false` I worked out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "problem", and I think what the book is saying is not correct. As far as I can tell, the reason why you see the changes on the website, even though caching is active, is that Rails 4 uses cache digests. For more information, check out:

http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/russian-doll-caching-cache-digests-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

When you changed `config.cache_classes` to `false`, you just told Rails to not automatically regenerate views with each request. That's why you stopped seeing changes, it's not because "caching" was working correctly.